# (C/C++/Go) Library for writing & reading optical media on macOS

Tags: library, osx, macos, optical-media

I'm aware of [libburn](https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/web/wiki) and related libraries for GNU/linux & various BSDs, but I'm looking for low-level control of my CD/DVD burner from (Go) code I write on macOS.

I'm looking to burn very simple multi-session discs (they don't even need to be ISO-9660 compliant, at all, so long as I can read them back), so I'd even be comfortable with writing a basic library myself — but I'm not sure what abstractions I'd build on top of (I only have the one DVD burner and would like this to be usable for others with different brands etc.)

Any tips on how to approach learning about this, or finding/using existing libraries would be very appreciated!